# What does eq_ref and ref types mean in MySQL explain

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, explain

When we prefix an SQL query with the keyword "explain" we get a table with some columns. Please tell me what is the "type" column. What does `eq_ref` and `ref` mean in that context.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I'll try an explanation...

**eq_ref** – imagine that you have two tables. Table A with columns (id, text) where id is a primary key. Table B with the same columns (id, text) where id is a primary key. Table A has the following data:

```
1, Hello 
2, How are
```

Table B has the following data:

```
1, world!
2, you?
```

Imagine eq_ref as JOIN between A and B:

```
select A.text, B.text where A.ID = B.ID
```

This JOIN is very fast because for each row scanned in table A there can be only **ONE** row in table B which satisfies the JOIN condition. One and no more than one. That is because B.id is UNIQUE.
Here you are: *pseudo code* which illustrates the processing at server side:

```
foreach (rowA in A)
{
    if (existsInBRowWithID(rowA.id)
    {
        addToResult(rowA.text, getRowInBWithID(rowA.id).text);
    }
}
```

**ref** - Now imagine another table C with columns (id, text) in which id an index but a non UNIQUE one. Table C has the following data:

```
1, John!
1, Jack!
```

Imagine ref as JOIN between A and C:

```
select A.text, C.text where A.ID = C.ID
```

Here you are: pseudo code illustrating the server side processing:

```
foreach (rowA in A)
{
    foreach (rowC in C)
    {
        if (rowA.id == rowC.id)
        {
            addToResult(rowA.text, rowC.text);
        }
    }
}
```

This JOIN is NOT as fast as the former one because for each row scanned in table A there are **SEVERAL** possible rows in table C which may satisfy the JOIN condition (nested loops). That is because C.ID is NOT UNIQUE.

Comment: perfect explanation !

Answer (score 35):

The "type" refers to the join type made in your request. From best to worst, here is the list :

- system
- const
- eq_ref
- ref
- range
- index
- all

You will find a more detailed explanation at the MySQL documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

Comment: yes, thank you, but am not looking for that...i have understood what system and const mean in that type....but what does eq_ref and ref mean? I have read the explanation in mysql documentation but couldn't understand it....